# Rails 3.2 Asset Pipeline with Passenger Endless Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, asset-pipeline, passenger

Having recently migrated my app to 3.2.1, it would seem I'm another developer struggling with the asset pipeline.

Everything looks ok, my assets are compiled and apparently served. In the source of my doc I can see this:

```
 <link href="/assets/application-4fac522109a7afaaa2f18ef9f1294e19.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And the link works just fine. However, neither my js or css actually load.

The only error I can actually see in the apache logs is this:

```
 cache: [GET /] miss
```

I have adjusted my apache configuration to include:

```
 XSendFile On
 ...
 <LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$"> 
    Header unset Last-Modified
    Header unset ETag 
    FileETag None   
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
 </LocationMatch>
```

Am deploying with capistrano and passenger.

Has anyone out there run into this issue?

Comment: Can you access http://yourhost.com/assets/application-4fac522109a7afaaa2f18ef9f1294e19.css ?

Comment: Yup, that's the most frustrating thing. I can open the css and js files just fine.

Comment: Can I ask what version of Rails you are migrating from?

Comment: Not sure if this is the same problem: http://blog.nathanhumbert.com/2012/01/rails-32-development-environment-asset.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think it was actually an issue with 1.9.3-p0. After rolling back to 1.9.2-p280 and recreating the stylesheets, life's better. Although I am still not confident I've fixed it... Ran into issues again yesterday.

Comment: Fixed a month later through trial and error. Full instructions [here...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437452/rails-3-2-asset-pipeline-with-thin-and-apache-not-finding-assets/9457748#9457748

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure you wipe out /your_app_path/tmp/cache. I usually wipe out the public/assets also. Then do a compile and restart the app. Many times this solves odd issues with the pipeline for me.

Comment: yeah, tried both of those. I can't see why I can open application.css in browser and yet it's not actually loaded... crazy

Comment: just to clarify, you can copy and paste the exact path into your browser and the file loads correctly?

Comment: That's correct. Both js and css are accessible in /assets/application.... No errors in firebug either. The application css contains all the required styles. And yet the pages load with no styling.